Snowflake External Function Sends GET request along with POST
I am facing a weird issue in which my snowflake external function is attempting to send a GET request.
When I try to call my external function using
select s3('s3://****/*****/'); 
It throws the error
remote service error: 403 '{"Message":"User: ****** is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: ****/GET/"}'; requests batch-id: *****:1:1:0:0; request batch size: 0 rows; request retries: 0; response time (last retry)
I am not sure why is snowflake external function attempting to access GET method when it is explicitly mentioned in docs that it uses only POST method.
Also I can confirm on my lambda (connected to api_getaway) that am receiving the POST request which is successfully being received processed. The output is also being sent back in snowflake requested format(the function suddenly stopped working, was working like a charm earlier).
Not sure how can I debug this.

I'm no expert, but I think the GET is for the authorization process, not the function itself.  And the error appears to be an authorization issue.  Is it possible your permissions have expired or changed?
